# Android MediaPlayer slows down the code flow

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I am trying to create sound effects for a game. 
But with using of MediaPlayer when sound effect starts playing - the game slows down for a bit of a second. 
And if I use a lot of sound effects - the game really works struggles. 
I guess something is wrong with my realization.

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
     super.onDraw(canvas);
     // ...
     if(somethingHappened) {
             final MediaPlayer mySound = MediaPlayer.create(getContext(), R.raw.sound1);
            mySound.start();
            //...
     }
     //...
}
```

Using short mp3 files

Comment: hmmm, such stuff should be done in some game loop(which should be a different thread) not in onDraw ... also **onDraw should only**, well, **draw** , based on some game state ...

Comment: try using AsyncTask for playing the sound

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better declare the media player as a field and create it only once in your onCreate() not in onDraw(). Right now, everytime onDraw() is called(which is usually a lot) you create a new Media Player, that eats up resources. 
Also good to do is mySound.pause() if its not needed and like Mounir says mySound.release() when you want to kill it.

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 ...
 final MediaPlayer mySound = MediaPlayer.create(getContext(),R.raw.sound1);
 ...

 }

protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
     super.onDraw(canvas);

 if(somethingHappened) {
        mySound.start();
 // might also want to call mySound.stop() at some point too
 }

 protected void onPause(){
     super.onPause();
     mySound.pause();
 }

 protected void onDestroy(){
     super.onDestroy();
     mySound.release();
 }
```

Comment: Thank you. Declaring as a field is a good idea. But how can I declare in onCreate as my current class extends View, not Activity?

Comment: Just declare it in your View class as a field(not in onCreate()) : private MediaPlayer mySound = MediaPlayer.create(getContext,R.raw.sound1); Moving all your mediaplayer stuff to your activity might not be a bad idea, so you can use an ASyncTask to play the sound, that should be best practise.

Answer (score 1):

Try cleaning up mySound:

```
public class MyService extends Service {
MediaPlayer mySound;
// ...

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
   if (mySound != null) mySound.release();
}
}
```

for more details:http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html

Hope this help!